# Boot from ISO on reboot is again installing it from ISO in icehouse

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-cinder

Below are the steps which I have followed.

```
$> neutron port-create int-net --mac-address  00:11:22:01:01:01 --name 1_eth0

$> cinder create --display-name disk1 100

$> nova boot --flavor iso_flavor --image iso --security-groups default --nic port-id=$(neutron port-list | grep  1_eth0 | awk '{print $2}') --block-device source=volume,dest=volume,id=$(cinder list | grep disk1 | awk '{print $2}'),bus=virtio,bootindex=1,type=disk ISO_VM

$> nova delete ISO_VM

$> neutron port-create int-net --mac-address  00:11:22:01:01:01 --name 1_eth0

$> nova boot --flavor iso_flavor --security-groups default --nic port-id=$(neutron port-list | grep  1_eth0 | awk '{print $2}')  --block-device-mapping vda=$(cinder list | grep disk1 | awk '{print $2}') ISO_FROM_VOLUME
```

After booting the VM, if we touch a file and restart, then the changes are not being present. Those were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Better go for 'Boot from snapshot' if you want to persist the changes.

1)Install & Configure OS.

2)Create snapshot using

`nova image-create --poll myInstance myInstanceSnapshot`

3) Verify by

`nova image-list`

4) You may boot from snapshot by.

`nova boot --flavor m1.tiny --image myInstanceSnapshot myNewInstance`

Comment: 1) install & configure OS means?

Comment: @SasikiranVaddi Install OS and install needed softwares if any

Comment: no i have to boot a VM from iso, this should install it on HDD. so which on reboot it loads from HDD  and data will remain exists even on rebooting instance.